# How to conditionally load the models in controller method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I am using **CodeIgniter** and **doctrine** for my project. When I enabled **CodeIgniter** profiling I got know My one request is taking 18MB of memory. I created test project with simple CI and Doctrine libraries. On test project **CRUD** operation takes 6 to 7 MB memory per request. After digging into to application I got to know included models are taking too much memory.

Earlier I loaded model into constructor method. But it consumes too much memory. 
I decided to load models into every method which are required to particular method.

Is that good approach?

Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No you should not load model in every method. instead try load the model in contructor of each controller file. Hope you understand my answer.

Comment: I already doing in my project but Models are taking 3MB memory for each request. If remove model from constructor then it reduce the memory.

Comment: fourty model files I am using in single controller.

Comment: Common model files should be at CI_controller library and controller should have only respective model file

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, we should load models conditionally.

1) You should write certain conditions in the construction function for loading models.

2) Also, only required/dependent models should be included in any controller.

3) Including model in every method load the page faster. But, its not the best practice.

4) Rather you should dig into your model codes and find out why do its taking this much amount of time to load.

Your approach is right.

Answer (score 0):

Use autoload.php to load models its makes to fully utilize the frameworks benefits

Comment: My concern about memory...as I do not want to load the model or libraries through autoload...I want to load model when ever that is required.

Comment: It Depends on how much you require that specific model ... and i dont think there would me any memory problems bro